# Gravity and the Speed of Light

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, speed-of-light, spacetime, cosmological-inflation

Let's assume that I am on an airplane that is at about 4,000 altitude and now let's also assume that I am standing on one of the wings with a light torch, if I point the light torch below to the surface, the photons will be attracted by gravity and hit the ground at their normal speed but if I point a light torch upwards, will the speed of light be slightly slowed (even by the slightest margin) due to the force of gravity?

Answer (score 1):

No, the wavelength will grow due to gravity, look up "gravitational red shift"

Comment: This might be a better answer if you explained the key points of gravitational redshift & how it applies here, rather then telling OP to go search it him/herself.

Comment: On the other hand, the questioner _is_ God, so...

Answer (score 1):

Light will always be measured to move at c in a "local inertial frame", see [this article on the equivalence principle](http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/equivalence_principle) for a discussion of what that means. If you use a non-inertial coordinate system, there is no requirement that light always moves at constant coordinate speed, so if you don't want to restrict things to inertial frames then the answer to your question would just depend on how you choose to construct your coordinate system.